# Website Disclosures to cover estimations/rounding/stale data

Tags: internet, consumer-protection

I am developing a website for a client, and we want to include some legalese in the disclosures that protects us against claims that our inforation was not correct:

1. Some facts/figures may be outdated (for example: status updates - there is currently a delay of up to 1 day due to the website scheduling all updates to be made live at 1AM everyday; if the content manager forgets to update the site, well that delay will be their tardines + however many hours until 1AM)
2. Some facts/figures are rounded pessimistically (for example, we may round 87,507 to 87,500)
3. Some facts/figures are best guesses/estimations with assumptions involved.

It is probably important to mention that none of the estimations are used in any sales capacity - basically just informational disclosures, general public record-keeping.

In terms of where this legalese will be placed, we want a solution where we can just place it on our legal-disclosures page. Something along the lines of: by visiting this website you automatically agree that you are aware of the fact that some figures are estimations/best guesses and therefore cannot make any claims of that you were mislead by the website. We do not want to modify any of the content outside of the legal-disclosures page.

I would be grateful if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction in my hunt for this solution. What type of attorneys should I be looking for or maybe there is some boilerplate legalese I could find somewhere? What type of clauses should I be including? I'm really lost -> i'm an engineer and have no experience in legal matters.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Law.SE.  It sounds like you're asking for specific legal advice, which we don't do here.  If you have a specific question about how the law works, we can answer that, but we don't give general advice about legal situations.

Answer (score 0):

> What type of attorneys should I be looking for?

You need an attorney with experience in contracts, website terms and user agreements; almost any attorney can draft such documents, but you can easily find one who has direct experience with website legal documents. Google in your area for business lawyers and call a few law offices; they will make recommendations.

> Or maybe there is some boilerplate legalese I could find somewhere?

You absolutely do not want to "roll your own" or find some boilerplate to copy. You will make critical errors that can at least render the documents legally moot, or at most get you sued.

Comment: thanks for the advice. when i call the lawyer, can i explain the situation over the phone? or do i need to first need to establish attorney-client relationship via some sort of contract + retainer fee?

Comment: Many attorneys will give a free initial consult for informational sake; then you can learn how much help you need and actually hire him/her.

Comment: during the consultation is the attorney-client relationship established? this is going in a different direction, but what if i was getting divorced and my spouse went to a divorce attorney i had a consultation with but ultimately did not select. would that attorney be allowed to represent my spouse? if not, is it because attorney-client relationship was established in my initial consultation?